# No matching function for call to a member function in class

Tags: c++

I am new to C++ and trying to make a program to calculate bond price, the original code works well but I have difficulties transferring it to OOP. mode. The program uses two arrays and a integer to do calculation. I used a loop in constructor to initialize data members (learned from stack over flow). it looks fine but I experienced one error like: no matching function for call to member function. the data can't be passed to member function. I was trapped here a whole day. Could anybody give me some insights? Thank you. The code follows:

```
#include <array>


#ifndef DRAFT_H
#define DRAFT_H


    class Draft
{
    public:

        Draft(int, double [], double[]);




        double F (double);
        void Bcalculator (int, double[], double[]);

        void printResult();
        void printDfactor();


    private:
        double discF[3]{};
        double bPrice {0};
        double bDuration {0};
        double bConvexity {0};

        double term[3];
        double cFlow[3];

        int sizeofArray;

    private:
};

#endif // DRAFT_H


#include "Draft.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


    Draft::Draft( int arraySize, double termArr[], double cFlowArr[]):sizeofArray{arraySize}{

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

        term[i] = termArr[i];
        cFlow[i] = cFlowArr[i];}

}




    double Draft::F (double x){
        return  0.05 / (1 + exp(-pow((1 + x),2)));
        }



    void Draft::Bcalculator(int sizeofArray, double term[], double cFlow[]){



        double a = 0;
        int n = 16;

        for (int k =0; k < sizeofArray; k++){

        double h = (term[k] - a)/n;

        double x[n], fx[n];

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
            x[i] = a + i * h;
            fx[i] = F(x[i]);
        }

        double result = 0;
        double discF[]{};

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i ++){
            if (i == 0 || i == n){
                result += fx[i];
            }
            else if (i % 2 != 0){
                result += 4 * fx[i];
            }
            else {
                result += 2 * fx[i];
            }

        }
        result = result * (h/3);

        discF[k] = exp (- result);
        bPrice += discF[k] * cFlow[k];
        bDuration += term[k] * cFlow[k] * discF[k];
        bConvexity += pow(term[k], 2) * cFlow[k] * discF[k];

}
        bDuration = bDuration / bPrice;
        bConvexity = bConvexity / bPrice;


}

    void Draft::printDfactor(){
        for (int k = 0; k < sizeofArray; k++) {

            cout << k + 1 << setw (20) << discF[k] << endl;
        }

}


    void Draft::printResult()
{
        cout << "Bond Price = " << setw(20) << bPrice << endl;
        cout << "Bond duration = " <<setw(20) << bDuration <<endl;
        cout << "Bond Convexity = " << setw(20) << bConvexity << "\n";
}


#include "Draft.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <array>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


    int main (){

        double termArray[3]{1, 2, 3};
        double cFlowArray[3]{5, 5, 105};
        int arraySize = 3;



        Draft bond1 (arraySize, termArray, cFlowArray);


        Draft::Bcalculator();

        bond1.printResult();

        bond1.printDfactor();


        return 0;
}
```

The error is:

> main.cpp|20|error: no matching function for call to
> 'Draft::Bcalculator include\Draft.h|18|note: candidate: 'void
> Draft::Bcalculator(int, double*, double*)'| include\Draft.h|18|note:
> candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided|

Comment: What is the complete error you're receiving? I assume it has something to do with `Draft::Bcalculator();`. It isn't a static function so you need to call it with an instance of the class, like `bond1.Bcalculator();` as you did with the other functions right below it.

Comment: A useful way to learn C++ is to take a situation like yours and concoct a [mre] demonstrating the error. Forget your goal of calculating a price and focus on the syntax related to this error. Figure out what is relevant, and get rid of the rest (in a copy of your project, of course). As long as the first error message does not change (other than the line and character numbers), you are on track for a simpler example.

Comment: main.cpp|20|error: no matching function for call to 'Draft::Bcalculator
include\Draft.h|18|note: candidate: 'void Draft::Bcalculator(int, double*, double*)'|
include\Draft.h|18|note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 0 provided|

Comment: Sorry, errors looked messy. I have one error now. it looks like the data can't be passed to member function to do calculation

Comment: Ok with that error (that I moved into the question) the compiler tells you on line 20 of main you call `Draft::Bcalculator();` with 0 parameters but it requires 3. The compiler is correct on this.

Comment: There's two problems, 1) How you're calling the function as I mentioned above, and 2) You're not passing the arguments the function expects. Since you pass those arguments to your class constructor I wouldn't expect that function to expect them again. I'd guess you want to remove them from the declaration in the class.

Comment: @Puckpicker `double x[n], fx[n];` -- Before anyone else mentions it, this is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time constant, not a variable.  Dynamic arrays in C++ are done this way:  `std::vector<double> x(n), fx(n);`.  Also, since you are new to C++, I am assuming you are using peer-reviewed C++ books to work from.  If so, there are no C++ books that shows the syntax that you're using to declare the arrays.  So the conclusion is that you're learning C++ from one of those poor websites that purport to teach you C++.

Comment: Hi Retired Njnjan, do you mean remove the loop?

Comment: @Paul, thank you very much for pointing out the issue and I learned something . Actually I will use vectors for next version of the program but now I have limited knowledge on vector and I will keep learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

1. Definition does not match call. You defined `Bcalculator` as:

   `void Draft::Bcalculator(int sizeofArray, double term[], double cFlow[])`

   But then you call it without arguments:

   `Draft::Bcalculator();`
2. To be able to call `Draft::Bcalculator()` you need to add `static` in the definition:

   `static void Draft::Bcalculator(int sizeofArray, double term[], double cFlow[])`

   If you do not want to make it `static`, call it the normal way, i.e. `Draft d{...}; d.Bcalculator()`.

**EDITED**

I realized that `Bcalculator` is using the same three parameters you use to construct and store in `Draft` class. Therefore, you should call `Bcalculator` without any arguments and use the class members `termArray`, `cFlowArray` and `arraySize`:

```
int main ()
{
    double termArray[3]{1, 2, 3};
    double cFlowArray[3]{5, 5, 105};
    int arraySize = 3;

    Draft bond1 (arraySize, termArray, cFlowArray);
    bond1.Bcalculator();
    bond1.printResult();
    bond1.printDfactor();
    return 0;
}
```

Then, your definition and implementation of this function has to be changed accordingly:

```
class Draft
{
public:
    ...
    void Bcalculator(); // <- remove parameters in this definition
private:
    double term[3];
    double cFlow[3];
    int sizeofArray;
}
void Draft::Bcalculator() // <- remove parameters in this implementation
{
    ... // use automatically the private members term, cFlow and sizeofArray
}
```

This code works, I compiled it.

Regards!

Comment: @ Victor, I defined Bcalculator static and then I had to declare variables inside the function static, ended with more errors. I guess I missed something else.

Comment: Hi Victor, thank you. it was a mistake to call function like Draft::Bcalculator(). it is not static function and should be called with normal way. I fixed it but still gave me same error. I will  keep tuning.

Comment: As long as a function uses a member variable it cannot be converted to static (unless those members are also static), that is why you see errors. Call `Bcalculator` creating first a `Draft` object and then calling its method, that must work.

Comment: I made a project bond1 and then called like below but still got same error.

Comment: Hi Victor, Thank you very^n much. you saved my program. a minor question, the function printDfactor doesn't function well, it prints disF[] out but the numbers are too small (near 0). Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome! I can only say that `discF` is calculated in your algorithm, if it is not what you expect, you need to readjust your calculation. Finally, please mark the question as the solved so that in the future others know the solution :)

Comment: Hi Victor, I removed a declaration of disF  in source file and then it is o.k. now.  you inspired me although I don't totally understand why it is working now. My deepest thanks : for (n =1; n<infinite; n++){cout << "THANKS" << endl;}

Comment: Hi Victor, Happy New Year.

Comment: Happy new year! Best wishes for a fresh new start :)